# Run ASP.NET core compiled app with https and command line

Tags: asp.net-core

When you build an ASP.NET Core executable, if you double click it, it starts the application under http://localhost:5000.

When you run it in Visual Studio it starts with both options (http/https).

Is there any way to do the same when starting the executable? Or at least set it to just start in https instead of http?

Comment: [enforcing-ssl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/enforcing-ssl?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: You're welcome. Hope that helps. Have a good day. :)